# Difference between two images Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have two images `A` and `B` of size `200x400`. Pixels(cell values) in both images will have values that range from 1-20 only. `A` is the correct image which have the correct values in each pixel. What I want to do is to check the pixels in image `A` having each value (1-20) and compare it to the corresponding values in image `B`. So for example, I will check the pixels in image `A` which has the value `1`, then will check those pixels in image `B` and check what values (1-20) those pixels have. Then will do the same thing for the rest of the values (2-20).
After that, I want to save the confusion matrix of the result in matrix `C`.

So if `A` is like this:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
4 1 1 1 1 1 3
3 1 1 1 1 1 6
6 1 1 1 1 1 4
6 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

and `B` is like this:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
4 2 1 1 4 1 3
3 4 1 8 1 1 6
6 1 2 7 1 1 4
6 1 1 5 4 1 2
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

and I want to check the pixels with value `1` in image `A` with the same pixels in matrix `B`. The this means that the pixels that I'm gonna work with are this box of 1's in image `A` and the corresponding pixels in image `B`.

And C would look like this (will only fill the row of the `1` as this is what I gave the simple example):

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ... 20
1  12  2   0   3   1   0   1   1   0 ...   
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
.
.
.
20
```

so as you can in image `A` there were 20 pixels having the value `1` but the corresponding pixels in image `B` has 12 ones, 2 twos, 3 fours, 1 five, 1 seven and 1 eight.

So this matrix `C` will be filled row by row with the number of occurrences of each of the column number in the row number pixels.

So if anyone could please advise how this can be done in Matlab, also please let me know if any more clarification needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
N = 20; %// possible pixel values are 1,2,...,N
result = accumarray(A(:), B(:), [N 1], ...
    @(x){reshape(histc(x, 1:N),[],1)}, {zeros(N,1)});
    %// each cell contains one row of the result matrix
    %// reshape needed because histc may output a row or a column vector
    %// (Note: fill value of accumarray can also be a cell)
result = [result{:}].'; %'// concatenate all cells into result matrix
```

Or more simply using the accumulation capabilities of [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
result = full(sparse(A(:), B(:), 1, N, N));
```

---

If the pixels may have `0` values, just add `1` to `A`, `B` and `N`:

```
result = accumarray(A(:)+1, B(:)+1, [N+1 1], ...
    @(x){reshape(histc(x, 1:N+1),[],1)}, {zeros(N+1,1)});
result = [result{:}].';
```

Or

```
result = full(sparse(A(:)+1, B(:)+1, 1, N+1, N+1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried both but the sparse one is not working. May be because in matrix B some of the pixels will have the background value which is zero? The accumarray solution worked if I set `N` to `21`, but the result will be `21x21`, and I'm not sure which rows are for the zero value or what the result represents because of this extra row and column. So if you could please advise

Comment: another thing I noticed when running the accumarray solution, is that sometimes `result` will be `21x1` but one of its cells will be `1x21` and the rest are normal `21x1`, I don't know why this happens.

Comment: @shepherd See edited answer, which adresses both issues

Comment: I still have this problem where some of the rows are switched to be `1x21` instead of `21x1`

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem after my correction. I think `reshape(...)` solves that. Can you post minimal `A`, `B` that cause the problem?

Comment: A and B are found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/to4nkg8iljfk9z5/matlab.mat?dl=0 where A=ref_masked, and B is res_masked. So if you could please advise.

Comment: With those data, using `N=22; result = accumarray(A(:)+1, B(:)+1, [N+1 1], @(x){reshape(histc(x, 1:N+1),[],1)}, {zeros(N+1,1)})` I get all cells of 23x1 size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75010/discussion-between-shepherd-and-luis-mendo).